# PowerShell: How can you collect the amount of tasks that are running in a Do/Until loop?

Tags: powershell, function, loops, while-loop, until-loop

Afternoon all,

I've got a script that runs scheduled tasks on some remote computers through Cimsessions.

```
Start-ScheduledTask -CimSession $CimSessions -TaskName "<Task-Name>"
```

I then have a timer that runs in a `Do/Until` loop until the tasks are completed. However, the loop ends when one server has completed the task even if others have finished. Is there a way I can re-write my loop to continue until all servers have registered that their task is `not running`

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
Do{
    $ElapsedTime = (Get-Date) - $StartTime
    $TotalTime = "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]$ElapsedTime.Ticks)
    $CurrentLine = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
    Write-Output "Running Scheduled Task... [Total Elapsed Time: $(stc $TotalTime yellow)]"
    sleep -s 2
    $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $CurrentLine

}Until((Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $CimSessions -TaskName "<Task-Name").State -ne 'Running')
```

**Note**: the line of code `$(stc $TotalTime yellow)` is just a custom function that changes the color of the text to yellow

Comment: I think, instead of `until` you could use `while((Get-ScheduledTask ....).State -contains 'Running')` if I understand correctly

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, you know, you really need to start posting things as an answer so I can give you the proper credit lol. but that small change helped! I forgot/didnt think about ``-contains`` operator

Comment: your fault for asking interesting questions while i'm also working :^) but you could self-answer explaining how you could solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition:

```
Until((Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $CimSessions -TaskName "<Task-Name>").State -ne 'Running')
```

Is saying, "run this loop and **stop as soon as there is one object with it's `State` property not equal to `Running`**". What you want instead is, "run this loop **while there are objects having the `State` property equal to `Running`**", hence the condition should be:

```
# with `-contains`
while((Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $CimSessions -TaskName "<Task-Name>").State -contains 'Running')

# with `-in`
while('Running' -in (Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $CimSessions -TaskName "<Task-Name>").State)
```

As aside, you could greatly simplify the task of `$ElapsedTime = (Get-Date) - $StartTime` by leveraging the [`StopWatch` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0). Here is a little example:

```
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
do {
    $timer.Elapsed.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss')
    Start-Sleep 1
} until($timer.Elapsed.Seconds -ge 5)
```

Comment: Appreciate the assist once again! And I’ll take a look at using the stopwatch class!